# rendering data table issue

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

i have created a component with a having data table whose values gets refresh when user changes the filter type.

On change, I am calling one controller method where I get contact details.

The strange behavior I have seen is that when I change filter suddenly the data table columns and its values disappear.

I don't understand where the issue is :

**Component code**

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }"/>

<aura:attribute name="selectedFilter" default="all" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="accountId" type="String" description="used to pass account id of contacts"/>

<!-- Data table attributes -->
<aura:attribute name="contactData" type="Object" description="Used in data table"/>
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List" description="Used show column data table"/> 
<aura:attribute name="columnsOther" type="List" description="Used show column data table"/> 
<c:avSpinner/>
<lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
    <!-- Contact list header component -->
    <lightning:layoutItem class="slds-p-bottom_small" size="12">
        <!-- New contact list header with buttons --> 
        <div class="slds-page-header">
            <div class="slds-media">
                <div class="slds-media__figure">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="standard:home"/>
                </div>  
                <div class="slds-media__body slds-align-middle">
                    <nav>
                        <ol class="slds-breadcrumb slds-line-height_reset">
                            <li class="slds-breadcrumb__item">
                                <span>Manage Contacts</span>
                            </li>
                            <li style="width:11rem">
                                <lightning:combobox name="contactFilter" value="{!v.selectedFilter}" options="{!v.options}" onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/>                                    
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-no-flex slds-grid slds-align-top">
                        <lightning:button label="New External Contact" onclick="{!c.cancel}"/>
                        <lightning:button label="New Internal Contact" onclick="{!c.createNewAssessment}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <!-- Assessment left panel component -->
    <lightning:layoutItem class="slds-size_7-of-7 slds-p-right_small">
        <div class="slds-card" style="min-height:500px">
            <!-- the container element determine the height of the datatable -->
            <div style="min-height: 300px">

                <lightning:datatable columns="{!v.columns }"
                                     data="{!v.contactData}"
                                     keyField="Name"
                                     showRowNumberColumn="false"
                                     rowNumberOffset="0"
                                     onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}"
                                     hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>


            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

**JS Controller code**

```
 ({
// Initialize default values from controller
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getDataTableRows(component, event, helper);     
}, 
handleChange : function(component, event, helper) {

    helper.handleChanges(component, event, helper); 
}
})
```

**helper code**

```
 ({
    handleChanges : function(component, event, helper) {        
    var action,state,errors,selectFilter,contactDetails,i;
    selectFilter = component.get("v.selectedFilter");
    action = component.get("c.getContactDetails");
    action.setParams({
        "filterType": component.get("v.selectedFilter"),
        "accountId" : component.get("v.accountId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        state = response.getState();
        if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
            contactDetails = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.contactData", contactDetails);       
        }else if (state === 'ERROR'){
            errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " +
                                errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }else{
            console.log('Something went wrong, Please check with your admin');
        }

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
getDataTableRows : function(component, event, helper){
    var selectedFilter,actions;
    selectedFilter =  component.get("v.selectedFilter");
    actions = [
        { label: $A.get("$Label.c.Edit_Button_Label"), name: 'edit'},
        { label: $A.get("$Label.c.Delete_Link"), name: 'delete'}
    ];


    component.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Title', fieldName: 'Title', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email'},
        {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'},

        {type: 'action', typeAttributes: {rowActions: actions}}
    ]);             


}
})
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for your aura method as well as a minimal reproducible code here?

Comment: please make sure that the data you have is compatible with the columns that you defined - you can post a sample to your question